# Rails : ActiveJob : Retry same job with some delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activejob

I am using active jobs and it works wonderfully well. As I was playing around, I noticed something and I'm looking for any improvements.

I have a job like:

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(param)

    # if condition then re-try after x minutes
    if condition
       self.class.set(:wait => x.minutes).perform_later(param)
       return
    end

    # something else
  end
end
```

Upon some condition, I am trying to re-schedule the current job after a `x` minutes `delay` with the same `original parameters`. The `scheduling` works great. But, there was some nuance that I observed at the database level and wanted an improvement.

The issue is a `new job` is created, a new `row` in the `db` table. Instead, I'd like to have it work as the `same job` just with some added `delay` (basically I want to modify the parameters to `re-schedule` the same `current job` with the same parameters obviously) .

I do realize that `raising an error` will probably do the trick, as far as working on the same job is concerned. One nice thing about that is the `attempts` gets incremented too. But, I'd like to be able to just add an `delay` before the job runs again (the same job, without creating a new one).

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you'll want to retry versus enqueuing a new job. Look at customizations by using the class method [`on_retry`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on)

Changing your code, it could look like:

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  retry_on RetrySomeJobException, wait: x.minutes

  def perform(param)

    raise RetrySomeJobException if condition

    # Do the work!
  end
end
```

Comment: note that this will retry a maximum of 5 times.

Comment: @aandis 5 times is the default. you can specifiy the number of attempts with an option e.g. `attempts: 10` or with umlimited attempts: `attempts: :unlimited`